# How to host a stic website of S3 in the aws ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster in which the keycloak application is running. I have an s3 bucket in which I hosted a static website and configured it with the route53 and cloud front.

Whenever any user is getting registered in the keycloak. Those users should be able to access the static website which is hosted in the S3. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the front end written in (like React, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Never done what you are specifically asking for, but solution would look something like this:

1. You determine if JWT from keycloak is enough for access
   Ideally this is yes. :)
2. You configure lambda@Edge to validate users
   This would read the JWT that keycloak provides - which ideally is enough.  If step 1 says you need more, then you would need the lambda@edge to do more than basic code and make a call back to keycloak
3. Lambda@edge authorizes call

There are several wikis / articles describing how to use lambda at edge.  This one leverages authorization header vs cookies...but a good starting point (
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-restrict-access-to-your-cloudfront-distribution-with-basic-authentication-e2cdae5fca7e).